# Boolean field update due to another field change in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have model `Department` like:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dep_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Title')
    dep_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Description')
    dep_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is Active?')
    dep_start = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Establishment')
    dep_end = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name='Closing Date', null=True)
```

and `DepartmentAdmin`:

```
class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('dep_title','dep_description','dep_status', 'dep_start', 'dep_end')
```

I want to check `dep_end` date and if date is expired, set automatically `dep_status = False`

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to override your save function. Like this:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dep_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Title')
    dep_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Description')
    dep_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is Active?')
    dep_start = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Establishment')
    dep_end = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name='Closing Date', null=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.dep_end > ## Expiration date here ##:
            self.dep_status = False
        super(Department, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now every time your model saves, it will check to see if the dep_end date is past your expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

You can also override `save_model` in `ModelAdmin` as

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import Department

class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if change and 'dep_end' in form.changed_data:
            if obj.dep_end < # your expiration date:
                obj.dep_status = False
            else:
                pass

admin.site.register(Department, DepartmentAdmin)
```

More details on [Django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)